# Adding each_slice (3) gives Error in Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, loops

I'm working on this `do` loop in my app, it works fine but I want to take it further (see below) and I'm not sure how to do that.

```
<div class="row">

    <% @products.each do |category, products| %>
        <% products.each_with_index do |product, index| %>
        <% if index == 0 %>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 center-block " >

                    <%= image_tag product.image.url(:medium), class: "img-responsive" %>
            <div class="caption">
                <p><%= product.category.name %></p>
             </div> 
            <% end %>
            </div> 
        <% end %>
    <% end %>

</div>
```

At the moment the loop is looping through 12 categories and displaying one image from each category. I don't want to have all the images appearing in the same row.

I tried to add `each_slice(3)` to the loop but it gives me this error:

> undefined method 'image' for 5:Fixnum

This is how the code looks after the `each_slice(3)` insertion

```
    <% @products.each_slice(3) do |category, products| %>
        <div class="row">
            <% products.each_with_index do |product, index| %>
                <% if index == 0 %>
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 center-block " >

                    <%= image_tag product.image.url(:medium), class: "img-responsive" %>
            <div class="caption">
                <p><%= product.category.name %></p>
             </div> 
            <% end %>
            </div> 
        <% end %>
    <% end %>

</div>
```

I'm not sure what to do here or if each_slice (3) is the right way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

array = [..]

array.each_slice(x) will give you array.size / x arrays different.

Example :

```
> [1,2,3,4,5,6].each_slice(2) do |g| p g end
[1, 2]
[3, 4]
[5, 6]
```

So you have to add a loop to your code :

```
<% @products.each_slice(3) do |products_group| %>
   <% products_group.each do |category, products| %>
   ...
   <% end %>
<%end%>
```

Comment: @olivergg thank you , this is it, it works like a charm :)